# Gridsome Pager is not working inside component

Tags: vue.js, pagination, pager, gridsome

If I use Pager with  inside the index is working, but when I use it inside a component I get is not working. Any help?

```
<Pager :info="$static.posts.pageInfo" />
```

and GraphQl

```
<static-query>
query Posts($page:Int){
  posts: allPost(perPage: 3, page: $page) @paginate{
    totalCount
    pageInfo {
      totalPages
      currentPage
      isFirst
      isLast
    }
    edges {
      node {
        title
        image
        id
        path
        excerpt
      }
    }
  }
}
</static-query>
```

Comment: Have you imported `Pager` to you component? `import { Pager } from 'gridsome'`, or globally

Comment: "If I use Pager with inside the index is working" - do you mean inside index.vue?

Comment: ihave used once on category and it's work perfectly

Comment: but in components not!

Comment: @Aliihane, I'm not sure I understand what you're saying... what do you mean by "inside the index"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<static-query>
query Posts($page:Int){
  posts: allPost(perPage: 3, page: $page) @paginate{
    totalCount
    pageInfo {
      totalPages
      currentPage
      isFirst
      isLast
    }
    edges {
      node {
        title
        image
        id
        path
        excerpt
      }
    }
  }
}
</static-query>
```